# Partial search on Solr in the end of the string

Tags: solr

I'm using Solr with partial search with this configuration:

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25" />
```

So I've indexed a word like "**mountain**", if I search "**mount**" I find the content.

But is there a way to perform a partial search in the middle or the and of a string?

I would like to search "**ountain**" and match "**mountain**".
Or to search "**ounta**" and match "**mountain**".

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you use an [NGramFilterFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/filter-descriptions.html#FilterDescriptions-N-GramFilter)

```
 <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25"/>
```

Of course, the size of your index will increase...